# Solve the improper integral $ b\int_{-\infty}^0 xe^x dx $

Tags: integration, limits, analysis, improper-integrals

$ b\int_{-\infty}^0 xe^x dx  $
my solution gets me to an undefined limit $0 \cdot (-\infty) $ while the answer is supposed to be 
 $-b$

my solution:
$ b\cdot\int xe^x dx =
 b \cdot e^x(x-1) = 
b \cdot ((e^0 \cdot (0 -1)) - (e^{-\infty}\cdot(-\infty - 1))  $
the first part equals to $-1$. The second is $-(0 \cdot(-\infty - 1))$, which is undefined limit. 
Am I wrong? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: the result is -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the integration variable from $x$ to $-x$ and you will get
$$
\int_\infty^0(-x)e^{-x}(-dx)=-\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}dx.
$$
Then, integrating by parts you will get
$$
\left.xe^{-x}\right|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty e^{-x}dx=-1.
$$
Use has been made of the fundamental limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}xe^{-x}=0$.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just by Hospital: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}xe^x=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{x}{e^{-x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{1}{-e^{-x}}=0$$ and also,$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}e^x=0.$$

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks

Comment: @Art You are welcome!